# How can I make an always visible, fillable hint in EditText?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

Is it possible to create in `EditText` something like the image below?

[image]

In first case there is no input.
In second case input is "1",
In third case input is "12",
In fourth case input is "123", and so on...

I tried to do this using `TextChangedListener`, but every time i setText like "0,0" + "1" it repeats reqursively.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way.
The reason is that you do a `setText` on the edittext, to avoid recursively calls on your `afterTextChanged` do:

1. removeTextChangedListener(yourWatcherObject)
2. Do your number format operation
3. addTextChangedListener(yourWatcherObject) again

To make the hint always visible you can use two editext, one over the other and play with the TextWatcher.

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful because i had previously performed operations on `onTextChanged`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want to use an EditText with multiple colors. You don't need use two or more EditText. You can do that easily using `SpannableString` object. With `SpannableString`, you can customize specific parts of your text as you want. ( size, color, type etc. ). You can use `setText` method of EditText to change text after the customization.

```
fun getSpannableText(): SpannableString {
    val text = "0,01"
    return SpannableString(text).apply {
        setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.DKGRAY), text.length - 1, text.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, text.length -1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]